# Using x-google-endpoints OpenAPI extension with multiple API versions in Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, openapi

I'm trying to deploy two API versions to Google Cloud Endpoints but end up facing configuration issues during the deployment.

API definition `api-1.yaml` looks like this:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "API"
  title: "API"
  version: "1.0.0"
host: "api.endpoints.GCP_PROJECT.cloud.goog"
basePath: "/v1"
x-google-api-name: v1
x-google-endpoints:
- name: "api.endpoints.GCP_PROJECT.cloud.goog"
  target: "IP_ADDRESS"
...
```

This works just fine if deployed alone. However if `api-2.yaml` is added:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "API"
  title: "API"
  version: "2.0.0"
host: "api.endpoints.GCP_PROJECT.cloud.goog"
basePath: "/v2"
x-google-api-name: v2
x-google-endpoints:
- name: "api.endpoints.GCP_PROJECT.cloud.goog"
  target: "IP_ADDRESS"
...
```

This leads to deployment error: `OpenAPI spec is invalid. Multiple endpoint entries are defined in the extension \'x-google-endpoints\'. At most one entry is allowed.`

Removing `x-google-endpoints` extension from one `yaml` file works but it leaves another `yaml` file as incomplete and thus, not optimal solution.

Could there be and issue with combining/validating `yaml` files during deployment? Can `x-google-endpoints` extension be used to define `.cloud.goog` domain for versioned API's?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

1) version is in the domain name, such as v1-api.endpoints.GCP_PROJECT.cloud.goog.
You define and deploy two services; one for v1 and another for v2.  Each has its own IP, proper service name and its own backend. This is most straightforward way and easy approach.

2) version is in the path, such as api.endpoints.GCP_PROJECT.cloud.goog/v1.  You can only define and deploy one service. But you have two backends.  This is tricky one. You can use [x-google-backend](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions) extension in the OpenApi spec and deploy one Cloud Endpoint service.

Comment: Option 2 was something I'm working with. There is `basePath` for `v1`and `v2`. How should I defined `x-google-endpoints` in this case? Guide here (https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/versioning-an-api#backwards-incompatible) says that I should just make separate openApi yaml files for each version but it seems `x-google-endpoints` cannot be duplicated to both.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two ESP proxy as:  `v1_esp -> v1`,  `v2_esp -> v2`.
Each proxy has its own IP and you are trying to bind a domain name to two IPs. This is not supported.

My suggestion is to use one ESP as such:

`esp -> v1 + v2` by using x-google-backend.

With the following:

1. In the openApi.yaml

```
paths:
   /v1/path1:
      ...
      x-google-backend:
        address:  v1_host
   # do above for all your path/methods

   /v2:
      ...
      x-google-backend:
        address:  v2_host
   # do above for all your path/methods

x-google-endpoints:
- name: "api.endpoints.GCP_PROJECT.cloud.goog"
  target: "IP_ADDRESS"
```

2. add --enable_backend_routing and --rewrite to remove /v1 and /v2 prefix before sending the request to your backends.

*We have not tested such deployment, but you can try it.*